# What does "javascript:;" do?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna know what `javascript:;` does in the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="notifications-handler">0</a>
```

I can't anything useful in Google so I wanted to ask you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a URL?  It doesn't do anything.  It's a convenient way of making the target of a clickable widget on a web page not do anything at all.

If it had actual Javascript code between the `javascript:` and the `;`, then it would do whatever that code said to do.

Comment: Other similar tricks include: javascript://, javascript:void(0);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `<a href="javascript:;">xxx</a>`, it's a way to make the link not do anything, but continue to behave like a link.

As you know, in links, the first bit can be a protocol, like `http:` or `https:` or `ftp:` or `mailto:`. `javascript:` is a pseudo-protocol that says "Treat the rest of this link as JavaScript code and run it."

In your example, the only code is `;`, which is the statement terminator, and so the JavaScript code does nothing.

You can also use `javascript:` pseudo-protocol in bookmarks, which is how [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) work.

Answer (score 0):

It is an empty expression. This is often used by `<a>` tags to fill href attribute and do something else in `onclick`.